# problem with cookies

Tags: php, cookies

i have a page that create a cookie value using the set_cookie like this:

```
setcookie("is_voted","1",time()+60*60*24*10,"/~poll/","spacepower.tv");
```

but i can't get this cookie value using the $_COOKIE array

how to fix this problem ?

Comment: If you are using `$_COOKIE` into the same script where you set the cookie, you are not getting any value since the cookie is registered in that script and will be available only after the first run.

Comment: What does the URL that checks for the cookie look like? If it's not within the `/~poll/` directory, it won't be available to the script. Setting the path to `/` will make it available to the entire domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem.  According to the PHP manual:

> Cookies will not become visible until
>   the next loading of a page that the
>   cookie should be visible for. To test
>   if a cookie was successfully set,
>   check for the cookie on a next loading
>   page before the cookie expires. Expire
>   time is set via the expire parameter.
>   A nice way to debug the existence of
>   cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

Basically, the $_COOKIE superglobal is only updated when the script first runs.  If you set a new cookie, it won't be immediately available in $_COOKIES.  You have to start a script to see updated $_COOKIE values.  If you don't see them *then*, you have a problem.

Comment: i'm using the $_COOKIE array to get the cookie value in a different file

Comment: are you sure that your browser is accepting cookies? If you don't accept cookies, it wont be set the next time a script checks the cookies.

Comment: if(isset($_COOKIE["is_voted"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["is_voted"])) {do something}

Answer (score 0):

According to php.net:

> Cookies are part of the HTTP header, so setcookie() must be called before any output is sent to the browser.

When they say before any output, they mean *any* output.  If there is any whitespace, including blank lines, outside of the `<?php ?>` blocks, it will cause the headers to be sent and the cookie will not be set.